# how to check if value in mutidimension array are the same?

Tags: php, if-statement, multidimensional-array

if I have multidimensional array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => Dummy
            [key] => 5501____I2-6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => Dummy
            [key] => 5497____I2-2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => Dummy
            [key] => 5502____I2-7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [value] => Dummy
            [key] => 5499____I2-4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [value] => Dummy
            [key] => 5496____I2-1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [value] => Dummy
            [key] => 5500____I2-5
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [value] => Dummy
            [key] => 5503____I2-8
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [value] => Dummy
            [key] => 5498____I2-3
        )

)
```

How can I check if each value in ***[value] =>*** are the same ?

thank for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php

Comment: Have you tried anything or just wait for code?

Comment: I have been trying  about this problem  . I use count function  and  unique_array   but It doesn't work in mutidimensional array. but If you have solution for fix it  please  help me thankyou  .

Comment: What doesn't work in your implementation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

For two-dimensional array you can check duplicate value by following.

```
$array = array();
$temp_array=array();
$array[0]['value']='Dummy';
$array[0]['key']='1';
$array[1]['value']='Dummy';
$array[1]['key']='2';
$array[2]['value']='Not Dummy';
$array[2]['key']='3';

foreach($array as $k=>$step1){
    if(in_array($step1['value'],$temp_array)){
        // In this you can find out duplicate values.
    }
    $temp_array[$k]=$step1['value'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thank everyone for help.

I found the way for fix it now.

I'm not sure it 's best way but It can fix this problem for me.

```
$data = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => Dummy
            [key] => 5501____I2-6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => Dummy
            [key] => 5497____I2-2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => Dummy
            [key] => 5502____I2-7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [value] => Dummy
            [key] => 5499____I2-4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [value] => Dummy
            [key] => 5496____I2-1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [value] => Dummy
            [key] => 5500____I2-5
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [value] => Dummy
            [key] => 5503____I2-8
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [value] => Dummy
            [key] => 5498____I2-3
        )

)

$newarray = array();
  for ($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
     array_push($newarray,$json_data[$i]['value']);
}
if (count(array_unique($newarray)) == 1){
   echo 'The same';
 }
else{
   echo 'not The same';
}
```